# How do I send Bugsnag notifices to stderr?

Tags: ruby, logging, io-redirection, stderr, bugsnag

I'm working on a Ruby software which may catch some errors (exceptions) and use Bugsnag to record the event in the Bugsnag logs.

For example, I may have something like this:

```
begin
  [...snip...]
rescue StandardError => e
  Bugsnag.notify(e)
end
```

What I'd like to be able to do is redirect the message logged by that line of code to my console. That way I could get it to my log file and then search on it and see what's before/after it and make sure things are working as expected.

Is there a way to setup Bugsnag to get such functionality?

Comment: Never used bugsnag, but what's wrong with adding `Rails.logger.error e`?

Comment: @anothermh If you have hundreds of `Bugsnag.notify(e)`, it's not practical to change them all to another log mechanism. That being said, I used `puts ...` in a few locations to verify that things were happening as expected. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an [On Error Callback](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ruby/rails/customizing-error-reports/#on-error-callbacks). This callback will be executed for every handled and unhandled exception.

```
Bugsnag.configure do |config|
  config.add_on_error(proc do |event|
    # redirect message to your console here
    
  end)
end
```